# SQL query to group specific events

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the below output for a SQL query using MySQL database.

So for each agent engagement accepted event I want to calculate the `cust-message` and the first agent message following that. Then again the first `cust-message` and first agent message following that. Below are two examples of the event. Can someone help with the SQL query.

I tried to use lead for the chat_event, and take the first `cust-message` and `agent-message` after that. the time is not coming correct specially where multiple `cust-messages` are there and multiple agent messages.

Input  1

```
chat_id agent_login chat_date_of_event  chat_event  rn
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:09:23 Agent Engagement Accepted   1
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:10:08 cust-message    1
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:11:10 agent-message   1
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:01 cust-message    2
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:10 agent-message   2
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:15 cust-message    3
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:22 cust-message    4
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:38 cust-message    5
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:52 agent-message   3
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:13:29 agent-message   4
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:13:39 agent-message   5
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:16:50 agent-message   6
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:18:59 agent-message   7
```

Output 1

```
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:10:08 2024-02-20 17:11:10 
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:01 2024-02-20 17:12:10 
986339  jbr 2024-02-20 17:12:15 2024-02-20 17:12:52
```

Test case 2
Input 2

```
chat_id agent_login chat_date_of_event  chat_event  rn
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:31:45 Agent Engagement Accepted   1
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:32:01 Agent Post  1
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:32:35 cust-message    1
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:33:15 agent-message   2
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:35:23 agent-message   3
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:35:44 cust-message    2
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:36:32 cust-message    3
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:40:23 Agent Engagement Accepted   1
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:41:29 agent-message   1
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:43:32 agent-message   2
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:44:34 cust-message    1
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:45:47 agent-message   3
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:47:48 agent-message   4
```

Output 2

```
98781   rmar    2024-02-21 21:32:35 2024-02-21 21:33:15
98781   jto 2024-02-21 21:44:34 2024-02-21 21:45:47
```

Thank you for the help.

```
WITH Events AS (
    SELECT 
        chat_id, 
        agent_login, 
        chat_date_of_event, 
        chat_event,
        LEAD(chat_event) OVER (PARTITION BY chat_id ORDER BY chat_date_of_event) AS next_event,
        LEAD(chat_date_of_event) OVER (PARTITION BY chat_id ORDER BY chat_date_of_event) AS next_event_time
    FROM 
        your_table_name
    WHERE 
        chat_event IN ('Agent Engagement Accepted', 'cust-message', 'agent-message')
),
EndUserPosts AS (
    SELECT 
        chat_id,
        agent_login,
        chat_date_of_event AS end_user_post_time,
        CASE
            WHEN next_event = 'agent-message' THEN next_event_time
            ELSE NULL
        END AS potential_agent_post_time
    FROM 
        Events
    WHERE 
        chat_event = 'cust-message'
),
FirstAgentPostPerUserPost AS (
    SELECT 
        e.chat_id,
        e.agent_login,
        e.end_user_post_time,
        MIN(a.potential_agent_post_time) OVER (PARTITION BY e.chat_id, e.agent_login, e.end_user_post_time) AS first_agent_post_time
    FROM 
        EndUserPosts e
    LEFT JOIN 
        Events a ON e.chat_id = a.chat_id AND e.agent_login = a.agent_login AND a.chat_date_of_event > e.end_user_post_time AND a.chat_event = 'agent-message'
    GROUP BY 
        e.chat_id, e.agent_login, e.end_user_post_time
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    chat_id,
    agent_login,
    end_user_post_time,
    first_agent_post_time
FROM 
    FirstAgentPostPerUserPost
WHERE 
    end_user_post_time < COALESCE(first_agent_post_time, '9999-12-31')
ORDER BY 
    chat_id, 
    agent_login, 
    end_user_post_time;
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried... this isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: And please tag only a **single** RDBMS... MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server.

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine whether an agent accepted the event? That is not clear from the data provided.

Comment: @MichaelGrogan Agent Engagement Accepted is the one which shows that it is accepted by agent.

Comment: @DaleK apologies for not posting it correctly. i have updated the post and provided the query that I have used on my side.

Comment: Does your input have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  state_changes AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN chat_event = 'Agent Engagement Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY chat_id, agent_login
            ORDER BY chat_date_of_event
      )
        AS chat_agent_engagement_id,
    LAG(chat_event)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY chat_id, agent_login
            ORDER BY chat_date_of_event
      )
        AS previous_chat_event
  FROM
    your_table
  WHERE
    chat_event IN ('Agent Engagement Accepted', 'cust-message', 'agent-message')
),
  lookahead AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(chat_date_of_event)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY chat_id, agent_login, chat_agent_engagement_id
            ORDER BY chat_date_of_event
      )
        AS next_timestamp
  FROM
    state_changes
  WHERE
        chat_event <> previous_chat_event
    AND chat_agent_engagement_id > 0
)
SELECT
  chat_id,
  agent_login,
  chat_agent_engagement_id,
  chat_date_of_event,
  next_timestamp
FROM
  lookahead
WHERE
      chat_event = 'cust-message'
  AND next_timestamp IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  chat_id,
  agent_login,
  chat_date_of_event
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/JWwg19jz